# Apple command line tool to validate ipa file before submitting to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I haven't found any other option so far to validate iOS builds on either ipa or app form than:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -verbose product.ipa
```

However in Xcode 6.0 and newer + Mavericks/Yosemite the only output I get on the console is:

```
Validating product.ipa -verbose warnings
```

Is there a way to just validate an ipa before submitting to the App Store?